# Sliding divs and toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a script that will slide a div up from the bottom of the page. The toggle button for this div however is going to be right on top of the sliding div. But, when the button is pressed and the div starts to slide down, the script hides the button. Here's an example...

http://www.codekraken.com/dashpad/testing/test2.html

How can I get the toggle button to slide with it, but not disappear?

Here's an example of what I mean:

[image: Screeshot]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NY9Xa/ something like this?? im ot sure wht you mean there is no button in test2.html only a hyperlink

Comment: No, look at the picture as it shows what I am trying to have happen. And click the hyperlink in test2.html to see the div slide down (reload the page, I changed it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a css problem not a JS problem.

Here is the solution: (if i got the question right)
http://jsfiddle.net/SdvWQ/

(Just wrap the dock and the trigger in a div)

PS: remove the if in your function and use `slideToggle()`.

Comment: What if I wanted to have 2 different divs that would slide. So you'd click one button and one div would slide, and you'd click another button and the other one would slide. Is that possible?

Comment: yes it is just make a function of my code and apply it to an other div to. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/SdvWQ/1/

Comment: Ok, I wanted to have one sliding on top and one on bottom, so I changed up the style a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/N9yan/4/

Answer (score 0):

The button is inside the container. Either move it out of the container div, or change this line

```
var container = $( "#container" );
```

to

```
var container = $( "#inner" );
```